# How to get the image name of a docker container from inside the container

Tags: docker

I need to get the name of the docker container that I am currently running, from within that container. The command that I use to run the container is

```
docker exec -it 9d05bea23030 bash
```

I am able to retrieve the ID of the container by typing

```
cat /etc/hostname
```

but I don't know how to get the name of the image. I am referring to the name that is shown under IMAGE when I type docker ps outside of the container. I need that specific name, as it contains crucial information.

Comment: try `cat /etc/*elease*`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This type of information/metadata is not passed into the container by default. There are 2 reasons for this.

1. if every metadata about the container was passed into the container, it could potentially pose a security risk when someone breaks into it
2. container shouldn't need this kind of information anyway

The reason why you can get access to container's ID from within the container is simply because it is used as the container's hostname by default. If you would specify hostname when running the container with `container run --hostname ...`, you wouldn't have access to the ID either.

I don't know why you need this information but the only way to get it when you are inside of the container is to first pass it to the container in one way or another. For example via an environment variable.

If you don't have access to this information from the outside of the container (which seems strange if you are able to use `docker exec`), you will not get it from the running container.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I do in fact have access to this information, but other users do not. The image name contains information that I would like to provide to those users. Could you elaborate how I could pass the name to the container via an environment variable, as you suggested?

Comment: to a running container? or via Dockerfile?

Comment: best would be to a running container, but if it can only be done via Dockerfile, I would try that, too

Comment: I would say that it would be best to set it in Dockerfile, otherwise the change will not perists but for example, you can log into the container, type `export IMAGE_NAME=nginx`, and then retrieve this information via `echo $IMAGE_NAME`. This should work on most containers but if not, you can always create a file inside and store the information in it and then let others access the file.

Comment: Consider passing given information as a label. For example traefik does use labels to read information about containers.